# How to set sublimecodeintel of sublime text 2 in Linux environment?

Tags: python, linux, sublimetext2, sublimecodeintel

Recently I tried to set sublimecodeintel for sublime text 2 to help my python development.But after several tests I cannot get the code completetion. 
I followed the directory of github:https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel
But I did not find the .codeintel/ in my home directory, so I created .codeintel and config file in it. After restart sublime there is not work and db file was not established in the .codeintel directory.

Who can help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the package manager of sublime text2 : https://sublime.wbond.net/installation
And just install plug-in in the list.

Works for me.